# ZeroMQ PUB/SUB not working on same machine on different JVM

Tags: java, zeromq

I am using Zero MQ PUB/SUB model where PUB and SUB are two different applications deployed on the same machine on webpshere 6.1. This model works fine on my local machine but when I deploy it on a remote unix box server it isn't working. My SUB never receives a message from PUB. I tried all the options suggested i could find on the web (localhost, 127.0.0.1) but no luck. Appreciate any help on this. I am using jeroMq 3.2.2.

Thanks
Akash

Answer (score 1):

If you're using multicast, then you need to enable loopback on the socket.  As a result of this, the sender app will get the data as well if it's listening for it.

Answer (score 1):

We also faced same issue and it was fixed by using below settings:

Publisher side use * (star) : tcp:// *.port number

Subscriber side use machine name : tcp://machine name of publisher.port number